# python - select div class with mechanize

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

I am trying to select a search bar and search a name. I have tried

```
for f in br.forms():
    print f
```

to see what forms are there, but it showed nothing. The page source on what I'm trying to select is:

```
<div class="inputOuter widget-search-outer employee_list-search " style=";width:470px;" onclick="">
   <div class="inputInner" style="">
      <input   onkeyup="SearchLimeList(event, 'https://crmcampaignmg.limelightcrm.com/admin/ajax_min.php?BUTTON_VALUE=employee_list&PAGE_ID=https%3A%2F%2Fcrmcampaignmg.limelightcrm.com%2Fadmin%2Fajax_min.php&LIST_NAME=employee_list&SQL_HASH=8e350ed23d50ac194cd486daaf8cab16&action=admin_admin.php_min_ajax_RenderEmployeeAccounts', 'employee_list', this, null);"  onclick=""  type="text" class="info-input search-ahead" style="" id="list_search_id_employee_list" name="list_search_name_employee_list" title="Search by Id or a list of Ids, Name, Description and more" value="" maxlength="">
   </div>
   <div class="widget-search-arrow " style="" onclick=""></div>
   <div class="widget-search-magnifier " style="" onclick="SearchLimeList(event, 'https://crmcampaignmg.limelightcrm.com/admin/ajax_min.php?BUTTON_VALUE=employee_list&PAGE_ID=https%3A%2F%2Fcrmcampaignmg.limelightcrm.com%2Fadmin%2Fajax_min.php&LIST_NAME=employee_list&SQL_HASH=8e350ed23d50ac194cd486daaf8cab16&action=admin_admin.php_min_ajax_RenderEmployeeAccounts', 'employee_list', this, null);"></div>
   <div id="list_search_id_employee_list_results" class="widget-search-drilldown" style="">
      <div class="widget-search-content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```